# Why is CDC capture failing due to a missing dbo principal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, change-data-capture

I am having a problem running the CDC change capture job against some of my test databases.

The error message I'm getting is the following:

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15517).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`dbo` is mapped to an invalid login. Re-map it to a valid one:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<dbname>] TO [sa];
```

Answer (score -1):

Under Security, add the principal as a "SQL user without login", make it own the schema with the same name as the principal and then in Membership make it db_owner.